# $watch a service when theres changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to watch changes in my services like in my system logs when there's someone who login the getlogs function must trigger how to achieve this ???

**dashboard.controller**

```
function getLogs() {
  return dataservice.getLogs().then(function (data) {
    vm.logs = data;
    return vm.logs;
  });
}
```

**dataservice.js**

```
function getLogs() {
  return $http.get('/api/timeLogs')
    .then(success)
    .catch(fail);

  function success(response) {
    return response.data;
  }

  function fail(e) {
    return exception.catcher('XHR Failed for getPeople')(e);
  }
}
```

I've tried this but its not working

```
 $scope.$watch('dataservice.getLogs()', function () {
  getLogs();
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case for observable pattern where you subscribe for changes on your service

```
app.service('dataservice', function($http) {
    var subscribers = [];
    var addSubscriber = function(func){
        subscribers.push(func);
    }
    var notifySubscribers = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i< subscribers.length; i++){
            subscribers[i](); //invoke the subscriber
        }
    };

    var addLog = function(){
        //let's say that the logs are added here

        //then notify the subscribers that a new log has been added
        notifySubscribers();
    };

    var getLogs = function() {
      return $http.get('/api/timeLogs')
        .then(success)
        .catch(fail);

      function success(response) {
        return response.data;
      }

      function fail(e) {
        return exception.catcher('XHR Failed for getPeople')(e);
      }
    };

    return {
        addSubscriber: addSubscriber,
        addLog: addLog,
        getLogs: getLogs
    }
});
```

Then in your controller add a subscriber function to the service

```
dataservice.addSubscriber(function(){

    console.log('new log added');
    dataservice.getLogs();
});
```

NOTE: this can also be done with the [RxJs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) library

Comment: I'm just confused on where will i call the getLogs and i'm still trying to apply your answer.

Comment: @Priz You should call the getLogs where you add the subscriber to the service. All functions that are added to the service suscriber array will get invoked when a new log is added(in my example)

Comment: i think i'm getting the idea about your answer but what i want to work is like handling a real time data. Just one question can i use your answer to create a notification service like facebook ? What i mean to say is  like a notification counter ???

Comment: @Priz The pattern itself is suitable for most cases where you need to notify a subscriber (user, program, service etc). So it will suit the notification service:)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check and get data's change from server, watching a service is not for that, use a polling service.

you check for every 1sec (for example) from a server:

example:

```
$interval(function() {
    dataservice.getLogs().then(function(data) {
        vm.logs = data;
    });
}, 1000);
```

or much  better:

```
getLogs = function () {
  dataservice.getLogs().then(function(data){
    vm.logs = data;
    $timeout(getLogs, 1000)
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there no other way ??? I don't want to send request to the server every 1 sec because it doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: $scope.$watch function check for every change on the $scope.. Angular uses dirty-checking and it could kill your app performance if you would get it to work.

Comment: i tried your answer but i cant use it my request loader keep appearing and the logs table keeps refreshing cant scroll down and cant use filter but thanks anyway i'll try to search about polling.